# Drawing a Petersen graph as a voltage graph

Tags: graphs

I am trying to illustrate a voltage graph construction of the Petersen graph.  In practice, this means:

- The outer cycle will be labelled clockwise (a,0),...,(a,4) with arcs oriented in that order;
- The inner cycle will be labelled clockwise (b,0),...,(b,4) with arcs (b,0) -> (b,2), (b,1) -> (b,3), (b,2) -> (b,4) and (b,3) -> (b,0); and
- Each (a,i) will be joined to the corresponding (b,i) (in that direction).

I can almost accomplish this using the grpetersen macro and the following code:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[->,>=triangle 45,rotate=90,scale=1.2,style=thick]
  \newcommand{\aset}[2]{$\{#1,#2\}$}
  \tikzset{VertexStyle/.style={draw,rectangle}}
  \SetVertexNoLabel
  \SetVertexMath
  \SetUpVertex[MinSize=30pt]
  \grPetersen[RA=3,RB=1.5]
%  \SetUpEdge{style={->-}}
  \AssignVertexLabel{a}{\textsl{(a,0)},\textsl{(a,4)},\textsl{(a,3)},\textsl{(a,2)},\textsl{(a,1)}}
  \AssignVertexLabel{b}{\textsl{(b,0)},\textsl{(b,4)},\textsl{(b,3)},\textsl{(b,2)},\textsl{(b,1)}}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

However, the arcs on the outer cycle are oriented in the wrong direction, and I cannot see how to change them without changing the other, correctly-oriented arcs.

Any suggestions would be much appreciated.

---

It is part of tkzgraph/berge - refer to Altermundus' "Plotting named graphs".  Here is a minimal document containing the above code.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tkz-graph}
\usepackage{tkz-berge}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[->,>=triangle 45,rotate=90,scale=1.2,style=thick]
  \newcommand{\aset}[2]{$\{#1,#2\}$}
  \tikzset{VertexStyle/.style={draw,rectangle}}
  \SetVertexNoLabel
  \SetVertexMath
  \SetUpVertex[MinSize=30pt]
  \grPetersen[RA=3,RB=1.5]
%  \SetUpEdge{style={->-}}
  \AssignVertexLabel{a}{\textsl{(a,0)},\textsl{(a,4)},\textsl{(a,3)},\textsl{(a,2)},\textsl{(a,1)}}
  \AssignVertexLabel{b}{\textsl{(b,0)},\textsl{(b,4)},\textsl{(b,3)},\textsl{(b,2)},\textsl{(b,1)}}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I'm afraid you'll have to hack the `\grPetersen` macro in the `tkz-berge.sty` file...

Comment: @CountZero Yes a hack is necessary. Better is to create with tkz-berge a new  macro to define something like `\grEmptyPetersen`.

Answer (score 2):

Here perhaps a solution. I modified my macro that I defined in *tkz-berge.sty*. The better way is to learn *tkz-berge* or to learn **tikz** to create your own macros. You can find some ideas inside the code of *tkz-berge* but you also look at the document *NamedGraphs* to find some examples  [NamedGraphs](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/tkz/tkz-berge/NamedGraphs)

Remark :tkz-berge loads tkz-graph and tikz

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tkz-berge} 
\makeatletter

\renewcommand*{\grPetersen}[1][]{%
\begingroup%
    \setkeys[GR]{cl}{#1}%
        \begin{scope}[<-]
            \grCycle[#1]{5}%     
        \end{scope}
        \edef\tkzb@rtemp{\cmdGR@cl@RB}
        \edef\tkzb@ptemp{\cmdGR@cl@prefixx}
        \grStartwo[#1,RA=\tkzb@rtemp,prefix=\tkzb@ptemp]{2}
        \EdgeIdentity{\cmdGR@cl@prefix}{\cmdGR@cl@prefixx}{5} 
\endgroup%
}  
\makeatother


\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[->,>=triangle 45,rotate=90,scale=1.2,style=thick]
  \newcommand{\aset}[2]{$\{#1,#2\}$}
  \tikzset{VertexStyle/.style={draw,rectangle}}
  \SetVertexNoLabel
  \SetVertexMath
  \SetUpVertex[MinSize=30pt]
  \grPetersen[RA=3,RB=1.5]
  \AssignVertexLabel{a}{\textsl{(a,0)},\textsl{(a,4)},\textsl{(a,3)},\textsl{(a,2)},\textsl{(a,1)}}
  \AssignVertexLabel{b}{\textsl{(b,0)},\textsl{(b,4)},\textsl{(b,3)},\textsl{(b,2)},\textsl{(b,1)}}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]